Wave generation with I2S on ESP32
Sine wave generated using calculation during runtime works well but using precalculated values messes it up? Why?
The pattern generated by using the function although does flicker a little but when using the table it gets too distorted and switches between 3-4 different partial sinewave patterns.
I generated the table using this website and configuration shown in this screenshot.
const int32_t sinTable[1024] = {
     0,   201,   402,   603,   804,  1005,  1206,
  1407,  1608,  1809,  2009,  2210,  2410,  2611,
  2811,  3012,  3212,  3412,  3612,  3811,  4011,
  ....... //shortend the table for the sake of simplicity
 -4609, -4410, -4210, -4011, -3811, -3612, -3412,
 -3212, -3012, -2811, -2611, -2410, -2210, -2009,
 -1809, -1608, -1407, -1206, -1005,  -804,  -603,
  -402,  -201 };

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <I2S.h>

#define I2S_SAMPLE_RATE (44100)
#define I2S_SAMPLE_BITS 16
#define PIN_LRC 33
#define PIN_BCLK 26
#define PIN_DOUT 25

#include "tables.h"
int count = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  I2S.setSckPin(PIN_BCLK);
  I2S.setFsPin(PIN_LRC);
  I2S.setDataPin(PIN_DOUT);
  if (!I2S.begin(I2S_PHILIPS_MODE, I2S_SAMPLE_RATE, I2S_SAMPLE_BITS)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize I2S!");
    while (1)
      ;  // do nothing
  }
}

int16_t GenerateSineWave() {
  double rad = 2 * M_PI * 1000 * count++ / I2S_SAMPLE_RATE;
  int16_t sineVal = 32767 * sin(rad);
  // int16_t sineVal = 32767 * (rad);
  return sineVal;
}

void loop() {

//Original Code: This works perfectly
  I2S.write(GenerateSineWave());
  I2S.write(GenerateSineWave());
  
//Alternative code to save calculation time. This doesn't work and create random wave patterns
  if (count > 1023) count = 0;
  I2S.write(sinTable[count]);
  count++;
}


I could not verify my theory, but I noticed that your table contains 32 bit values, and the GenerateSineWave function returns 16 bit values... Could you test with your code only running once from 0 to 1023 and then stop? The output might teach us something ...
